# How to set a conditional delay for making a request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array of symbols as shown below. 
For each element of the array I am making an Ajax request.

```
var symbols = ["SSS", "SEE"]

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each(symbols, function (index, value) {
        loadXMLDoc(value);
    });
});

function loadXMLDoc(value) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://ganaga/aaaa/sss',
        success: function (data) {}
    }
```

In the browser console, I see many XHR requests under pending state.
Is it possible to make the next Ajax request only when the response has been obtained for the previous array element?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 2):

```
var symbols = ["SSS", "SEE"]

$(document).ready(function () {
   loadXMLDoc(symbols);
});

function loadXMLDoc(symbols) {
   if(symbols[0]) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://ganaga/aaaa/sss',
        success: function(data){ loadXMLDoc(symbols.slice(1)) }
      });
   }
}
```

There is no `value` being used in `loadXMLDoc` in your question, I suppose you want:

```
        url: 'https://ganaga/aaaa/'+ symbols[0],
```

Also, I would rename function to `loadXMLDocs`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a little recursion:

```
var symbols = ["SSS", "SEE"]

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadXMLDoc(0);
});

function loadXMLDoc(idx) {
    value = symbols[idx];
    if (value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://ganaga/aaaa/' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                //...
                loadXMLDoc(idx+1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Invoke the next AJAX call in the callback function.

```
function loadXMLDoc(n) {
    var value = symbols[n];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://ganaga/aaaa/sss',
        success: function (data) {
            if (n < symbols.length-1) {
                loadXMLDoc(n+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Start it with:

```
loadXMLDoc(0);
```